# showing a BIG image with html

Tags: jquery, html, image, canvas

I am new in web development.
I find this web, http://digitalarchive.mcmaster.ca/islandora/object/macrepo:66896.
The map image is actually about 1GB in size.
I really want to know how can they do it.
Seems the browser requests a small part of the image when I zoom in or pan the map. But I have no idea how to do it. May please anyone suggest some keyword for me to study more?
really thanks!!.

Comment: Check progressive enhancement, stream bufferring may be?

Comment: the implementation they use is called OpenSeadragon https://openseadragon.github.io/

Comment: This is a map of tiles. Each tile is independently downloaded by the browser. There should exist tiles for each zoom level and for each zone you want to download.

Comment: as @ssice said, the image is split up into different tiles. So you need to convert your image first https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/

Answer (score 1):

They have sliced the image in square parts called tiles.

[image]

Each tile has a metadata associated to it, something like an index and at what level of zoom should it be used.

The tiles are cashed in layers depending of the zoom. When you move around the image you are sending to the server your bounding box (coordinates of the image that you see, also called bbox) Using this information the server calculates what tiles it should fetch you:

[image: Network profiler]

In the site that you showed each request for an image ends with something like this `svc.region=6144%2C12288%2C256%2C256&svc.level=4` Which states the bounding box (svc.region) and the zoom (svc.level)

A more advanced server that is capable of doing this (but specializes in geo data) is: [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/)

And for the visialization take a a look at [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/)

Also a nice explanation you can find [here](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/how-web-maps-work/)

Credits for the image *www.mapbox.com*

Comment: Also, there is a reason they slice big images. Some browsers limit the image size in browsers, for example [iOS Resource Limits](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15) and for maps there are other reasons: you do not need all tiles at once, you need tiles in various resolutions, easy to edit, etc.